# Можно ли подключать скрипты на отдельных страницах?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Такой вопрос, есть большой интернет магазин, и я почему то взял за правило, нужные скрипты подключать там где они используются, т.е. не в теге head, а там где нужно, это же касается и style. Делаю для того что бы лишний раз не грузить память. На сколько верно так делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне себе правильный подход, особенно для js. К примеру, для фронтенда (та часть сайта, которую могут видеть все пользователи) один набор, для админки - другой и т.д.

Многие backend-фреймворки имеют набор виджетов на том же jquery. В том месте, где вы указываете свой виджет, размещается и js логика данного виджета. Вот, собственно, и ваш сценарий - выборочные страницы.

Но есть замечание. js логика виджета инкапсулируется внутри фреймворка и фактически не повторяется в отличие от ручной вставки js логики во вьюхи. Кроме того, в последнем случае, можно и потерять в каком именно шаблоне у вас находится js логика, ибо шаблоны имеют возможность встраиваться друг в друга (chunks).

Answer (score 1):

В то время, как сама идея (избавления от ненужных ассетов) вполне хорошая, текущая реализация легко вас повергнет в ад менеджмента, когда для небольших изменений вам придется перелопачивать тонны кода. К тому же легко попасть в ситуацию, когда при повторении виджета его скрипт окажется на странице дважды, и, в том случае, если его внутренности как-то влияют на глобальное состояние, все может закончиться очень плачевно. Вам нужна система контроля ассетов, и тут я могу предложить два решения:

#### [kriswallsmith/assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic)

Assetic - это PHP-библиотека, созданная специально для управления ассетами. Она позволяет написать набор необходимых ассетов и вывалить их одним/несколькими файлами на странице. В этом случае все ассеты с каждой страницы будут собраны в одном месте.

#### [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

RequireJS позволяет указать в каждом js-файле его зависимости. В результате на каждой странице нужно будет указать один (главный) js-файл, который будет тащить необходимые зависимости, избавляя от необходимости следить за конкретными названиями файлов вообще. Кроме RequireJS есть еще стандарт загрузки CommonJS, но основная идея за ними одна и та же: скрипты сами объявляют, кто им нужен, и фреймворк подгружает эти скрипты.

Comment: Cчитаю `requirejs` лишней библиотекой. Только увеличит объем js логики. Полная поддержка ES6 не за горами. А пока, лучше конкатенация и минимизация Gulp-ом.

Comment: @romeo "есть готовое решение" - "скоро будет полноценное решение, а пока не будем пользоваться никаким". Конкатенацию, кстати, тоже тогда стоит забанить из-за http 2.0.

Comment: `Конкатенацию, кстати, тоже тогда стоит забанить из-за http 2.0` Согласен, и объеденение icon-графики в спрайты. Вот когда http 2.0 до нас доедет (в nginx [только-только добавили](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=43011) - 1.9), тогда и [модули](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) глядишь подтянутся. Я, кстати, не против использования препроцессор/transpilers (babel, TypoScript,...).

Comment: Есть мнение, что requirejs используют для той же [минимизации + конкатенации](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), а не для AMD, как, собственно, и позиционируется.

Comment: @romeo я здесь не рекомендую его ни для минимизации, ни для конкатенации.